# SplitViewController detailViewComtroller's NavigationBar color changes to pink grayish

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisplitviewcontroller

When i change detailViewcontroller in splitviewcontroller its navigation bar color changes to Pinkish gray color. Not able to understand why happening this.

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

```
If you customise  your navigation bar then your view will disappear into set your main view (parent) view color

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     //Set Your color of navigation bar.
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    //Set your color of main view controller (parent view color).
  [[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor your color]];

}
```

Comment: Thans Renish for answer. Here problem is i am not setting any color to    navigation bar for detailviewcontroller, but by default some pinkish gray color is applying on navigation bar. when i set any color navigation bar actual color is not applying, instead showing some color which is mixture of pink and new applied color.

Comment: pls can u upload screenshot here? and if you want customise color of navigation bar then set color in suggested both method .like,[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:myColor];

Comment: if your hierarchy is customise then sometimes it display the Window navigation bar color.in that case u set color of window.