# Hiding -> showing UINavigationBar causes colour change

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar

I am experiencing a strange problem where hiding and then showing an UINavigationBar causes it to change colour to permanently black so I can't set its colour.

Simple example where the NaviationBar initially is set to a grey tint:

```
// NavigationBar Colour is initially set - this works
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor red]];

// Then it is hidden and then shown
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
....
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

The status bar tint colour is now BLACK and can not be changed by setting appearance or directly setting the colour.

Can anyone explain this and know the solution to fix this?

Comment: you can set status bar color either white or black. but you are using navigation controller so status bar automatically set it's color same as navBar color. so what is your real problem ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the ´Status Bar´ - I have a UINavigationController with a UINavigationBar which colour is e.g. red. At some point I need to hide and show it again later on, when I set hidden = NO, it is shown again but the colour has changed to black and can not be set to anything else as usually possible.

Comment: I have checked in ios 7.1 and it does not goes back to black screen

Comment: It is not the screen but the navigation bar.

Answer (score -3):

```
    When you set the color of navigation bar then put your appropriate code into **view Will appea**r and **View Will Disappear method**. When you do transition between view then it's set the Main view (Window) Navigation bar color. We discuss topic in this link.   

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539913/splitviewcontroller-detailviewcomtrollers-navigationbar-color-changes-to-pink-g/23540110?noredirect=1#comment36113939_23540110
```

Comment: Please try to be more specific - right now this is not the solution as I am unable to change the colour after the NavigationBar has been hidden and unhidden.